# how to call function from child block magento

Tags: php, magento

How can i call functions that are defined in the child block in phtml file if i have a xml structure like

```
<block 
  type="test_test/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_giftregistry" 
  name="tab_test_main"
  template="test/test/customer/main.phtml">
  <block 
   type="test_test/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_giftregistry_list"
   name="tab_test_list"
   as="giftregistry_list"/>
</block>
```

I want to call function defined in "adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_giftregistry_list" block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a child bock object and call the fuction as shown below:

```
$myblock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('myblock'); 
echo $myblock->mymethod();
```

In your module :

```
$listblock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('test_test/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_giftregistry_list'); 
echo $listblock->yourmethod();
```

Cheers :-)

Comment: its giving me TypeError: this.blockMsg is null error

Comment: Did you replaced with your method name and tried? And What is your child method is returning? Is there method is present in child block only?

Comment: thanks for your reply girish finally got the solution now i m using  getBlockSingleton() instead of getBlock() its working fine